# Django url passing as many parameters as you want delimited by /

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

How can I define the URL pattern so that I can pass to an URL as many parameters as I want? I really researched the documentation and other stackoverflow questions but I didn't found something similar to that. I need this to work as a filter for an ecommerce website.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<str:var1>-<str:var2>/<str:var3>-<str:var4>/...', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

And in my view function I would define it like that:

```
def test(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do whatever you want with kwargs
    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a wrong way to make a path, if you want to use it as a filter instead of using it in the path you should use url parameters as a get request.

But if you insist on doing that you can use the [Regular expressions 're_path'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^test/(?P<path>.*)$', views.test, name='test'),
    # or use url instead it's same thing
    url(r'^test/(?P<path>.*)$', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

Comment: I really have no clue how to use regex. I will look at tutorials about that. I'm just having one question: Will  re_path help me achieve what I asked for?

Comment: @B.Victor Check the edited answer I add the code that you need

Comment: It actually will give you only one parameter 'path' but from this parameter I can split the string as I want and then manipulate it as I want. Thanks

Comment: Another option is to use `path('test/<path:path>', views.test, name='test')`. The `path:` converter means it matches slashes.

Comment: Note that `url()` was deprecated in Django 3.1, so it's not recommended to use it in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `query_params`?

That is `path('test', views.test, name='test')`

URL: /test/?filter=asd....

Then access it via the request in the view:

```
def test(request):
    params = request.GET.get('filter', None)
    return HttpResponse()
```

See if you can work out your problem like that :)

Comment: I understand your point but I really need a custom URL path that would be delimited by /. But anyways your point is quite valid overall.